# Tensorflow: tf.rnn.raw_rnn - fn_loop not callable?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, recurrent-neural-network, callable

I try to use a custom function for the loop_fn in an raw_rnn but there is this weird

```
"raise TypeError("loop_fn must be a callable")"  # Exception thrown?
```

Call:

```
callable_loop_fn = loop_fn(
    time=time,
    previous_output=None,
    previous_state=None,
    previous_loop_state=None,
    _W=W, _b=b,
    _decoder_lengths=decoder_lengths,
    _pad_step_embedded=pad_step_embedded,
    _eos_step_embedded=eos_step_embedded,
    _encoder_final_state=encoder_final_state)

# using the functions for the attention decoder
decoder_outputs_ta, decoder_final_state, decoder_loop_state = tf.nn.raw_rnn(decoder_cell, callable_loop_fn)
```

Definition:

```
def loop_fn(time, previous_output, previous_state, previous_loop_state, _W, _b, _decoder_lengths, _pad_step_embedded, _eos_step_embedded, _encoder_final_state):
if previous_state is None:
    assert previous_output is None and previous_state is None
    return loop_fn_initial(_decoder_lengths, _eos_step_embedded, _encoder_final_state)
else:
    return loop_fn_transition(time, previous_output, previous_state, previous_loop_state, _W, _b, _decoder_lengths, _pad_step_embedded)
```

Does someone know what this could be? I thought the function I provide is callable or did I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`callable_loop_fn` is not a function, therefore it is not callable.

Specifically, `callable_loop_fn` is the value returned by `loop_fn()` which, in turn, returns either the output of `loop_fn_initial()` or the output of `loop_fn_initial()`. Evidently, none of these two function returns a function hence the exception `loop_fn must be a callable` is thrown.

According to [TF API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn), you should write:

```
def loop_fn(time, cell_output, cell_state, loop_state):
    ...
    return (
        elements_finished, 
        next_input, 
        next_cell_state,
        emit_output, 
        next_loop_state
    )
```

And then pass it to `tf.nn.raw_rnn`:

```
raw_rnn(decoder_cell, loop_fn)
```

Note that you should respect the number and the order of the arguments that `loop_fn` expects to receive, otherwise you'll get error on `Unexpected argument` for the function `loop_fn`. Therefore, your implementation must be rearranged to only take 4 arguments.

Comment: I had this function and it worked. (but without custom extra parameters) my return of `loop_fn_inital`and `loop_fn_transition`is formated like the output tf wants:
`return (
        elements_finished, 
        next_input, 
        next_cell_state,
        emit_output, 
        next_loop_state
    )`

I will try some things later and see if it works. Because I need the extra parameters and don't want to give them via global scope...

Comment: To keep all your arguments, you can group them inside one (or more) dictionary.